# Changing the sign_in url for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do you change the sign in path for Devise when using a before_filter :athenticate user?

I have the following in a Posts controller.

eg:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

At the moment it automatically goes to '/users/sign_in'

I'd like to use '/login'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorted for now folks, using the devise_for method.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }, :path => 'accounts', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification' }
```

So now the sign_in path is 'accounts/login'

Comment: I think that if you add a prefix slash (`:path => '/'`) as a path it will use the root url's. But I'm not sure as I'm not to confident about routing in Rails 3.

Answer (score 4):

That solution doesn't modify the resource path for sign_in.

I did however sort it out via the devise_for method. eg:

```
devise_for :users, 
           :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' },  
           :path => 'accounts', 
           :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', 
                            :sign_up => 'new', 
                            :sign_out => 'logout', 
                            :password => 'secret', 
                            :confirmation => 'verification' }
```

So now the sign_in path is 'accounts/login'

Answer (score 2):

I think the info you are looking for is here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Stolen from the docs:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

In you case you would use :post instead of :user I believe.
Its late and I am fuzzy headed but I think that should do it.

Comment: Thanks Mike although that solution doesn't modify the resource path for sign_in. I did however sort it out via the devise_for method. eg:

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations' }, :path => 'accounts', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout', :password => 'secret', :confirmation => 'verification' }

So now the sign_in path is 'accounts/login'