# Rails 4, Devise Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created custom routes to route to the devise login and logout paths:

```
devise_scope :admin do
  get "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
  get "login" => "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
end
```

This works. The only problem is that if the the login fails it redirects back to `admins/sign_in` instead of `/login`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836648/877472) help at all? Additionally, [this descriptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836648/877472) seems to indicate the same thing. Basically looks like you need to use the `:path_names` options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836648/877472) and [this description](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes#another-simple-way-to-do-the-same-thing), it seems the proper way to achieve what you're attempting to do is to make use of the `:path_names` option. According to the description from the Devise wiki:

```
devise_for :admin, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

will create the normal `admin` routes for you, and will assign the `/sign_in` and `/sign_out` route to `/login/` and `/logout` respectively.

Using the `:path` option, you can further alter the URL, such as using `:path=>"admins"` will yield routes like `/admin/login`, etc.